# Change the base url / context path for a karaf/osgi blueprint web app

Tags: jetty, osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint, pax

I have a Web app with several servlets configured in my OSGI-INF/blueprint/web-blueprint.xml using pax web. The web app consists of two pages /LoginPage.html and /Dashboard.html, but the latter supports several views, each associated with an own angular controller and related backend servlet.

I can reach the two pages by the URLs `https://<ip>:<port>/LoginPage.html` and `https://<ip>:<port>/Dashboard.html`. Accessing `https://<ip>:<port>/` redirects to `https://<ip>:<port>/LoginPage.html`.

If we call `https://<ip>:<port>/` the base URL, I would like now to change this base URL to something like `https://<ip>:<port>/test/` so that

1. the login and dashboard pages are available under `https://<ip>:<port>/test/LoginPage.html` and `https://<ip>:<port>/test/Dashboard.html` respectively, and
2. `https://<ip>:<port>/test` simply redirects to `https://<ip>:<port>/test/LoginPage.html`.

Because the file `etc/org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg` specifies `etc/jetty.xml` as its config file, I was assuming that I can configure this in jetty.xml. The current jetty.xml is the standard one. jetty documentation says that one can set the context path by adding the following:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/test</Set>
</Configure>
```

But, adding simply the above to the end of the standard jetty conf file causes that my web pages are not reachable at all. I cannot find any further documentation or example how I could get this work...

I would appreciate any help very much!

Answer (score 0):

Please specify which Pax Web version you're using. In Pax Web 8, whiteboard context configuration and selection is fully implemented.

There's [a blueprint example that declares servlets, filters, error pages and welcome files](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/main/samples/samples-whiteboard/whiteboard-blueprint/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml) but it doesn't do what you want (you want to register a `ServletContextHelper` whiteboard service).

There's also [a whiteboard non-blueprint sample](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/main/samples/samples-whiteboard/whiteboard-extended/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/extender/samples/whiteboard/internal/Activator.java) that registers a context using non-standard `org.ops4j.pax.web.service.whiteboard.HttpContextMapping`.

So I can't point you to proper sample, but in short words, you need three things:

1. **an implementation of `org.osgi.service.http.context.ServletContextHelper`**

You have to extend this class, because it's abstract. You could also reuse `org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.context.DefaultServletContextHelper`

2. **a whiteboard context** based on the above:

```xml
<service interface="org.osgi.service.http.context.ServletContextHelper">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.http.whiteboard.context.name" value="my-name" />
        <entry key="osgi.http.whiteboard.context.path" value="/test" />
    </service-properties>
    <bean class="org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.context.DefaultServletContextHelper" />
</service>
```

3. **a servlet referring to the above context**:

```xml
<service id="my-servlet" interface="javax.servlet.Servlet">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.http.whiteboard.servlet.name" value="my-servlet" />
        <entry key="osgi.http.whiteboard.context.select" value="(osgi.http.whiteboard.context.name=my-context)" />
    </service-properties>
    <bean class="com.example.MyServlet" />
</service>
```

Pax Web 8 correctly handles *context selection* using standard Whiteboard service registration properties.